# QR code scanner using webcam with VB.net or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, webcam, qr-code

I'm working on a a thesis and I'm in need of a QR-code scanner using a webcam..
I searched and the library is paid.

I need a tutorial or a source code to finish this. I prefer a tutorial so I can learn it, not just download it and run it.. any links that can help me will do!

Please please..

Comment: "the library"? There are many libraries, you can certainly find one that is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Capture-QR-code-in-Windows-f665a28d
check this example. This solution use a nuget package and it's free.

Comment: Don't post link only answers. Please provide some more information with it

Comment: ok sorry @tarzanbappa, The example project is from windows dev center and use the ZXing package from nuget. This project use CaptureElement for show the camera and scan the QR code. This answer is fine? I'm new in stackoverflow

Comment: @tarzanbappa Yes, it's correct that normally posting links isn't enough. But in this case the TO asked for a tutorial and and Sturnino posted a tutorial. What should he do? Copy and paste the tutorial code? That's not even better. So in this case Santurnino's answer seems to be fine for me.